# Pass tags (with spaces) to an ARM template using Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am using Azure DevOps Pipelines to deploy an ARM template. My template has a tags parameter that I pass into the pipeline using `AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3`.

My ARM template has a value in parameters section as an object. `tags` is an object, which is what many of the sample templates show:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "resourceName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the name of the resource, including its prefix."
      }
    },
    "tags": {
      "type": "object",
      "defaultValue": {
        "Cost Center": "Admin"
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "name": "[parameters('resourceName')]",
      "properties": {
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "tags": "[parameters('tags')]"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Edited to match the thread that follows]

I am using `ubuntu-latest` for my pool. Tags may have spaces.

In my pipeline for *simplicity*, I set the tags to a variable.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
variables:
  - name: tags
    value: ("Location Region=West US 2" "Environment=${{ parameters.environment }}")
```

When I call the template deployment, I am passing in the tags as an `overrideParameters`

```
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    displayName: "Deploy my templateaccount"
    inputs:
      deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
      azureResourceManagerConnection: 'ResourceManager-connection'
      subscriptionId: ${{ parameters.subscriptionid }}
      action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
      resourceGroupName: '$(resourceGroupName)'
      location: '${{ parameters.location }}'
      templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
      csmFile: 'mytemplatelocation/azuredeploy.json'
      overrideParameters: -resourceName abcdefg76534 -tags "$(tags)"
      deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
      deploymentOutputs: resourceOutput
  - pwsh: Write-Output '$(resourceOutput)'
```

So far I have not understood how `AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3` on Ubuntu is expecting the tags to be sent.

In each case, the template fails to deploy.

Is this scenario supported in Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Anyone with a suggestion?

Comment: Could you share the error you're receiving?

Comment: The error is ##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'Template parameter JToken type is not valid. Expected 'Object'. Actual 'String'. Please see https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for usage details.'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format for the tags that worked in Azure DevOps pipeline `AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3` is to use JSON for your ARM Template objects, such as tags.

- Left curly bracket, colon separating the key value pairs, and comma separating the tags.
- Each key and the value in my case worked with quotes.
- A right curly bracket.

But following templates works by passing in a JSON object: `{"Cost Center":"DevTest","Location":"West US"}` as your template parameter. In context this looks like:

```
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'ResourceManager-connection'
    subscriptionId: 'XXXXX'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'rg-wus2-exampletest'
    location: 'West US 2'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: 'storageaccount/example.azuredeploy.json'
    csmParametersFile: 'storageaccount/azuredeploy.parameters.json'
    overrideParameters: '-resourceName oweruhsow -resourceTags {"Cost Center":"DevTest","Location":"West US"}'
    deploymentMode: 'Complete'
```

This Pipeline module is expecting JSON objects, not the same format used elsewhere with PowerShell (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resource) to deploy from the command line.

Also as a side note, other posts suggested that you name use something other than `tags` for your tags parameter. The one that worked for me is `resourceTags`. Here is my ARM template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "resourceName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the name of the resource"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for the resources."
      }
    },
    "resourceTags": {
      "type": "object",
      "defaultValue": {
        "Cost Center": "Admin"
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "name": "[parameters('resourceName')]",
      "properties": {
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want to set your template object as a the variable, you then can pass it in using the DevOps variable such as `$(tags)`:

```
variables:
  tags: '{"Cost Center":"DevTest","Location":"West US"}'
steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'ResourceManager-connection'
    subscriptionId: '9f241d6e-16e2-4b2b-a485-cc546f04799b'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'rg-wus2-exampletest'
    location: 'West US 2'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: 'storageaccount/example.azuredeploy.json'
    csmParametersFile: 'storageaccount/azuredeploy.parameters.json'
    overrideParameters: '-resourceName oweruhso11w -resourceTags $(tags)'
    deploymentMode: 'Complete'
```

Also (as a side note), for some reason, the module needed to have a `csmParametersFile` or it would just fail with something about failing with `RESOURCEGROUP` in all caps. The param file is not needed to deploy from the command line, but Pipelines modules does seem to require it.
A `csmParamters` file that can have just about nothing in it, but it seems to be needed.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": { }
  }
```

This also works using the `pool` `image: windows-latest`

Many thanks to ToMakesSense in the post at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/9051

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, or no longer does. I still get the error "The provided value for the template parameter 'resourceTags' is not valid. Expected a value of type 'Object', but received a value of type 'String'."

Answer (score 1):

If the parameter value you're using has multiple words, enclose them in quotes, even if you're passing them using variables.

For example, -name "parameter value" -name2 "$(var)".

Try to use below format:

```
overrideParameters: -location "${{ parameters.location }}" -tags "$(tags)"
```

More details please refer our official doc here-- [Azure Resource Group Deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion. I had really hoped it would work. I have updated the templates per your suggestion so perhaps you can reproduce the error. Unfortunately the error still persists.

Comment: @Bruce According to your error, seems there is a template valid error. This parameters   "tags": {
      "type": "object", are treated as string  not object. According to official doc, seems you should use a different name https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resources#apply-an-object .Besides, you could also try to use your template locally instead through Azure DevOps check if this works. It will help to narrow down the issue