# Is it possible to create an Azure Resource Group with tags in a YAML pipeline?

Tags: azure, yaml, devops, azure-resource-manager

There is a policy on our subscription that prevents anyone from creating a resource group without supplying tags for it at the same time.

> Failed to create the resource group. Error: "Resource 'my-new-resource-group' was disallowed by policy. Policy identifiers: '[{"policyAssignment":{"name":"Require a tag on resource groups" etc...

In the ARM template, I'm able to specify the tags as the resources are created. I can't seem to do that with the actual resource group...

The task I'm using is as follows:

```
    - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
      displayName: Deploy ARM Template
      inputs:
        deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
        azureResourceManagerConnection: '<<SERVICE CONNECTION>>'
        subscriptionId: '<<SUBSCRIPTIONID>>'
        action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
        resourceGroupName: "rg-$(resourcePrefix)-$(environmentShortName)"
        location: 'North Europe'
        templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
        csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop-iac/webapi.json'
        csmParametersFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop-iac/webapi.parameters.json'
        deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

Is there a way to specify the tags during this task? Searching the documentation didn't yield any useful information

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass tags (with spaces) to an ARM template using Azure Devops Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364524/pass-tags-with-spaces-to-an-arm-template-using-azure-devops-pipeline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick's answer is very comprehensive and from what I've seen correct.

The one addition here that could work is a PowerShell task above the ARM template Deployment [Creating/Updating the Resource Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroup?view=azps-6.0.0) as needed.  Within a YAML pipeline this may look like:

```
- powershell: New-AzResourceGroup -Name RG01 -Location "South Central US" -Tag @{Department="Marketing"}
```

The downside here of course is the PowerShell is a onetime run since it creates the Resource Group.  Better recommendation might be to have a separate PowerShell script check if the Resource Group is present if so create it, if not do nothing/update tags. This script would be called before the ARM template deployment.

Comment: As this answer offers a solution, I'll mark it. Nick's answer also provided useful info.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to set the tags using the `AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3` task with the `deploymentScope` set to `Resource Group`, as documented [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md#parameters-of-the-task) there are no parameters that do that. However, it is possible if you change the `deploymentScope` to `Subscription` but this will require you to refactor your template as a Subscription template.  This will allow you to define the Resource Group inside the template, along with it's tags, rather than relying on the `AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3` task to create it.

There's documentation on Subscription templates [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-to-subscription?tabs=azure-cli) but in short you will need to:

- add a resource to your template to define the [Resource Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.resources/resourcegroups?tabs=json)
- move the resources that are currently defined in the template to [linked templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell#linked-template) and replace them with [Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.resources/deployments?tabs=json) resources that deploy those linked templates

If your ARM templates are stored in a public repo that should be straightforward, if not you'll need to make them accessible over https in some way.  In the past I've used an Azure storage account and granted access to the files using a SAS token but there are many other ways to solve that problem.